# Geometrical application of generation function for permutation

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, geometry, visualization

It is quite well known that the generation function for permutations  is represented as
$$(1+x)(1+x+x^2)\dots(1+x+x^2+x^3...+x^{n−1})$$
(See, e.g., question [The generating function for permutations indexed by number of inversions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90292/the-generating-function-for-permutations-indexed-by-number-of-inversions))

I am looking for any examples to see application of the g.f. in geometry and particulary any geometrical visualization of the generation function.

Any ideas, problems, examples of visualization?